# iOS simulator not launching after Xcode and VS update

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

Can't get iOS Simulator to launch from Visual Studio. Xcode version: 10, VS Version: 15.8.7. Simulator just shows that is is "Connecting to Mac" and "Checking server"->"Connected". Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem with you two days ago. I updated my Visual Studio to the latest version 15.8.8 and then I can launch the iOS Simulator.

Here are my suggestions:

- Try to update you Visual Studio to the latest version 15.8.8.
- Try to open the iOS simulator before building your project on Visual
  Studio 2017.
- Try to restart your PC and MAC.